# Is it good practice to reuse the id in other routes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to know if it is good practice to reuse the id generated in other routes, I am saving in the node `employee`, then this same id I reuse it in the `settlements/settlement` and `settelement/regLiquidacion` node, I keep them with the same id to then look for it faster, to delete, update, do you want to know if it is good practice to reuse the id?

my first node where I have the user

```
employees
        -KwvdJ8uT-AoKKDFvUly
            name: luis
            rut: 111111
```

then reuse its id in the other nodes, in order to maintain an order and quick access to the data spread over other nodes

```
settlements/regLiquidaciones
       -KwvdJ8uT-AoKKDFvUly
           status: true
           date: date


settlements/liquidaciones
       -KwvdJ8uT-AoKKDFvUly
          montoLiquido: 90000
          montoBruto:900090
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a very common pattern and generally encouraged.  As you said, by using the employee ID as part of the path for the employees settlements, you can deterministically construct the path to that data and read without first querying.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up by query should be as fast as by id because each field is indexed automatically.
Reusing the id probably bring you only harder-to-read source code.